# Check for specific digits in a number

Tags: c#, puzzle

I want to check for certain digits in a number and based on the result it should print a message.

Digits to check: 7 and 9
Output: if 7,Print S and if 9, Print N(Order is important) and no 7 or 9,Print input number.

for ex:

input number:75  Output: S(Contains 7)

input number:96 Output: N(Contains 9)

input number:79 Output: SN

input number:97  Output: NS

input number:67849  Output: SN

input number:59587 Output: NS

input number:873579 Output: SSN

input number:135 Output: 135

I tried the following approach

```
string output = string.Empty;
        int n = 0;
        while(number > 0)
        {
            n = number % 10;
            number = number / 10;
            if(n == 7)
            {
                output += "S";
            }
            if(n == 9)
            {
                output += "N";
            }                

        }

        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(output) ? number.ToString() : output;
```

But this is working only if it contains one digit(for ex: works for 17,91)

It's not working if it has multiple numbers(for ex:769,957)

How to achieve this(**Order is important**).

Thanks in advance

Comment: That puzzle tag has the explicit note "DO NOT USE". You might want to use something that better describes your question.

Comment: why you do some calculations if you just want to get specific result in a number?

Comment: The program does exactly what you described except for the `135` case because `number` is always `0` at the end of the method and the output is reversed ([see fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/mAqqXl)). Include the rest of the code and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Just go to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16620665/1698987) answer. It's classic FizzBuzz. You can see plenty of how to do there with code examples (or just google FizzBuzz c# )

Comment: @Noctis all the examples provided are for checking for divisible not for containing a digit.Thanks

Comment: and ... ? iterate over all your digits, if it's divisible by 7 add s, if it's divisible by 9 add n ... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would convert to string first, therefore no math calculation is required and it will preserve the order.

```
string numberStr = number.ToString();
string result = null; // no need to use StringBuilder, because size won't be big
foreach (char c in numberStr)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case '7':
            result +='S';
            break;
        case '9':
            result +='N';
            break;
    }
}
return string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) ? numberStr : result;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can transform your number into a string and then iterate and when you find 7 you'll print S and with 9 N

```
 double myNUmber = 769.957;
                string myString = myNUmber.ToString();
                string output = string.Empty;
                for (int i = 0; i < myString.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (myString[i] == '7')
                        output += "S";
                    else if (myString[i] == '9')
                        output += "N";

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Easier way is to convert number to string first.

```
var numberStr = number.ToString();
var e = numberStr.Select(x => x == '7' ? "S" : x == '9' ? "N" : "");
var output = string.Join("", e);
return string.IsNullOrEmpty(output) ? numberStr : output;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(demo(75));
            Console.WriteLine(demo(96));
            Console.WriteLine(demo(79));
            Console.WriteLine(demo(97));
            Console.WriteLine(demo(67849));
            Console.WriteLine(demo(59587));
            Console.WriteLine(demo(873579));
            Console.WriteLine(demo(135));

        }

        static string demo(int number)
        {
            string result = new string(
                number.ToString().Where(digit => digit == '7' || digit == '9')
                .Select(digit => (digit == '7') ? 'S' : 'N' )
                .ToArray());

            return result.Length > 0 ? result : number.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Alternative #1:

```
static readonly string[] lookup = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "S", "", "N"};

static string demo(int number)
{
    string txt = number.ToString();
    string result = string.Concat(txt.Select(digit => lookup[digit-'0']));
    return result.Length > 0 ? result : txt;
}
```

Alternative #2:

```
static string demo(int number)
{
    string txt = number.ToString();
    string result = string.Concat(txt.Select(digit => "       S N"[digit-'0'])).Replace(" ", "");
    return result.Length > 0 ? result : txt;
}
```

Alternative #3 (technically a "one-liner" but I split it up)

```
static string demo(int number)
{
    return new string(
        number.ToString()
        .Select(digit => "0123456S8N"[digit - '0'])
        .GroupBy(digit => digit == 'S' || digit == 'N')
        .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
        .Last()
        .ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your method. One more this you should use StringBuilder instead of string to improve performance. you can pass long in place of int if you want.

```
public static string ProcessValidImport(int number)
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    int n = number;
    while (number > 0)
    {

        if (number % 10 == 7)
        {
            output.Append("S");
        }
        if (number % 10 == 9)
        {
            output.Append("N");
        }
        number = number / 10;
    }

    return (output == null  || output.Length == 0 ) ? n.ToString() : Reverse(output.ToString());
}

public static string Reverse(string s)
{
    char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(charArray);
    return new string(charArray);
}
```

I tries the OP solution, he has to reveres the string also.

you can use the below solution, If you want SEVEN and NINE instead of S and N.

```
public static string ProcessValidImport(int number)
{
    List<string> output = new List<string>();
    int n = number;
    while (number > 0)
    {

        if (number % 10 == 7)
        {
           output.Add("SEVEN");
        }
        if (number % 10 == 9)
        {
            output.Add("NINE");
        }
        number = number / 10;
    }
    output.Reverse();
    return (output == null  || output.Count == 0 ) ? n.ToString() : string.Join("", output.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Hey Vivek,Thanks for the solution.But my real time solution output has more than one character(SEVEN and NINE).For simplicity purpose I wrote it as S and N.

Comment: Because of reverse,the output is showing as NEVES and ENIN.Can we modify for this error

Comment: Yes, why not. start adding "SEVEN " and "NINE" to array instead of 'S' and 'N' and then reverse the array and convert it to string

Comment: Instead of reversing the array and converting it to string,I feel converting number to string solution is optimal.I am trying by not converting to a string.Thanks

Comment: Okay, let me know if you need any help

Comment: @Santosh I have updated my answer with your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading your number from the end, so your resulting string is backwards. (`997` gives `SNN`, when it is supposed to give `NNS`)

Instead of using this:

```
output += "S"; //or "N"
```

use:

```
output = "S" + output; // or "N"
```